# How to find out which app uses which Proxy?

Tags: windows, networking, virtual-machine, proxy, cntlm

So two things first:

I am not very well-versed in proxies and related topics and
my work environment is an absolute nightmare.

I have a windows Host machine with the proxy set up (however Chrome ignores that somehow, while IE (default for intranet pages) doesnt.
On Top of that I acutally work inside an Ubuntu VM using CNTLM to get the proxy to run.
That proxy itself then distributes me to either company-intranet, customer-intranet or internet.

However, some programs try to bypass cntlm and some dont.

Is there any GENERAL approach/tool  on how to find out:

1. which website is in which network
2. which program is using the proxy

The 2nd point isn't as important since you can just check the programs individually, but if there is a general fits-all-programs-approach I could save a lot of time by not digging through every single setting

Comment: I would check the proxy logs for that. In every record there should be source IP and agent (i.e. application) requesting connection. By that depends on proxy type.
When you set proxy in IE this applies to the whole Windows configuration. If the app is able to use these IE proxy settings - it will go through proxy. Otherwise it will ignore these settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @Hardoman pointed out: 
The proxy logs were the answer.
While they are painful to crawl through, I found my answers there